# Array out of range with check function

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I've got an array and a check function.

Function when tapped on button:

```
// VARS
var workoutArray: [workout]!
var index = Int()

@IBAction func finishExerciseBtnPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    // reload tabledata with next exercise in array

    print("the count of array is \(workoutArray.count)")

    if index <= workoutArray.count {
        index = index + 1
        tableView.reloadData()
        print("The exercise number is \(index)")
    } else {
        // Show finish workout button
        print("No items found anymore")
    }
}
```

Function of `tableView` `dequeReusableCell`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "workoutStartCell", for: indexPath) as? workoutStartCell {

        let workout = workoutArray[index]
        cell.updateUI(workout: workout, exercise: index + 1)

        return cell

    }else{
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

I am sending from a previous `viewcontroller` the number 0 to the index var on the top of this vc. I have the check method `finishExercisePressed` but whatever I am doing it keeps counting trough. It says index out of range but I am checking if the index is equal or lower to the count of the arrays.

This is the thing I would like to achieve:

[image]

Can somebody help me out please?

Thanks alot.

Comment: avoid being returned empty cells

Comment: What does `index` represent? Is this the number of the current workout?

Comment: The index represents: - The number of sets in that current workout. I will change the name cause its not a good naming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am checking if the index is equal or lower to the count of the arrays.

That's right. However, you are doing it before incrementing the index, and since indexing starts at zero, you should stop one index before the end:

```
var index = 1 // Set the index to 1 initially to skip the title
...
if index+1 < workoutArray.count {
    index += 1
    tableView.reloadData()
    ...
}
```

The above check verifies that `index` would stay in range *after* being incremented.

Comment: The problem is that I am showing my results in a tableView. But the title should start with 1,2,3 etc

Comment: tahts why I am incrementing in the tableview

Comment: I have added a picture for you

Comment: So from the previous viewcontroller he gets the number: 0 but which will be overrided in the tableview where the cells are generated. index + 1 so it gets the number 1 directly on the load